# Manually Restart a Countdown Timer on a Form in Access Database

Tags: forms, ms-access, time, counter

I have the following code to log off Access users automatically.

Most work will be completed in 5 minutes or less, but I would like to add a manual reset button below the counter that will restart the timer if needed.

I want to force the end user to manually start the timer over if needed.

```
Option Compare Database
Dim TimeCount As Long

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Me.TimerInterval = 1000

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()
TimeCount = TimeCount + 1
Me.txtCounter.Value = 1200 - TimeCount
If TimeCount = 1201 Then
    DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveAll
End If
End Sub
```

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: You don't know what your code does or what is the issue? Welcome to SO please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I have code to quit Access if the user is inactive. I know this isn't what you're looking for but it may help you out...if not, good luck!

Create a form called **DetectIdleTime**. Have it open when the database is loaded with the Window Mode set to Hidden.

On the OnTimer event in the DetectIdletime properties...

Sub Form_Timer()

```
     Const IDLEMINUTES = 5

     Static PrevControlName As String
     Static PrevFormName As String
     Static ExpiredTime

     Dim ActiveFormName As String
     Dim ActiveControlName As String
     Dim ExpiredMinutes

     On Error Resume Next

     ActiveFormName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
     If Err Then
        ActiveFormName = "No Active Form"
        Err = 0
     End If

     ActiveControlName = Screen.ActiveControl.Name
        If Err Then
        ActiveControlName = "No Active Control"
        Err = 0
     End If

     If (PrevControlName = "") Or (PrevFormName = "") _
       Or (ActiveFormName <> PrevFormName) _
       Or (ActiveControlName <> PrevControlName) Then
        PrevControlName = ActiveControlName
        PrevFormName = ActiveFormName
        ExpiredTime = 0
     Else

        ExpiredTime = ExpiredTime + Me.TimerInterval
     End If

     ExpiredMinutes = (ExpiredTime / 1000) / 60
     If ExpiredMinutes >= IDLEMINUTES Then
        ExpiredTime = 0
        IdleTimeDetected ExpiredMinutes
     End If
  End Sub
```

Set the Timer Interval event on the DetectIdleTime form to 1000

Now Access will close if the user doesn't move the mouse...